# How to access variable in another function and plugin in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to access variable from one function in another, but it results in nothing.

First function is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_custom_field_on_order_edit_pages', 10, 1 );
function display_custom_field_on_order_edit_pages( $order ){
global $my_field_name;
$my_field_name = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'my_field_name', true );
if( $my_field_name == 1 )
    echo '<p><strong>Фирменный пакет: </strong> <span style="color:red;">Добавить</span></p>';
    global $form_name;
$form_name = "Test form 1";
echo $form_name;
}
```

And I'm trying to access *form_name* here

```
if( function_exists( 'YITH_PDF_Invoice' ) ){
if( ! function_exists( 'yith_ywpi_print_document_notes' ) ){
    function yith_ywpi_print_document_notes( $notes, $document ){
        if( is_object( $document ) && ! empty( $document->order ) && $document->order instanceof WC_Order){
            /**
             * @var $order WC_Order
             */
            $order = $document->order;
            $shipping_info = $form_name;
            $notes .= $shipping_info;
           }
        return $notes;

    }
}
add_filter( 'yith_ywpi_print_document_notes', 'yith_ywpi_print_document_notes', 10, 2 );
```

Is there any other way to declare global variable? Or another way to access $form_name in other plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a global variable like this:

`$GLOBALS['foo'] = 'bar'`

You should then be able to access that variable from within other functions like this:

`$foo = $GLOBALS['foo']`

Read more about global variables in PHP [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php7/php7_superglobals.asp)